# How to change column properties of DataGridView which is (datatable bounded at runtime)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Columns are added in my datagridview at runtime.. That is why I Am unable to edit columns in design view and change their properties like i want my ItemName Column AutoSizeMode to Fill..

How can i access such properties in coding???

My database code is...

```
 public void LoadData()
  {
    con = new SqlConnection("Server=.; database=STORE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM;    Trusted_Connection=True;");
          SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  tbl_ItemDetail.ItemCode, tbl_ItemDetail.ItemName, tbl_Stock.Quantity,  tbl_ItemDetail.Price, tbl_ItemDetail.Category, tbl_ItemDetail.Size,  tbl_ItemDetail.Brand FROM tbl_ItemDetail, tbl_Stock WHERE  tbl_ItemDetail.ItemCode=tbl_Stock.ItemCode", con);
          dt = new DataTable();
          sda.Fill(dt);
          dataGridView_CRUD.DataSource = dt;
  }
```

[DataGridView Image at RunTime...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va2zd.png)

Comment: Please show the code where you call the `LoadData()`, I am looking for `dataGridView_CRUD.DataBind()`.

Comment: I called LoadData() in form load event.. But i do not call dataGridView_CRUD.DataBind(); Please tell me What is DataBind() method?? What it will do??

Comment: I have no idea about DataBind() method...

Comment: You *can* use the Designer. Assign the names of the DataSource fields to the `DataPropertyName` of each Column and set the other properties. At run-time, your DataSource fields will be bound to the Columns which have a corresponding `DataPropertyName` value. (Of course, if you know the fields names in advance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jimi Answer solved my problem...

"You can use the Designer. Assign the names of the DataSource fields to the **DataPropertyName** of each Column and set the other properties.

At run-time, your DataSource fields will be bound to the Columns which have a corresponding DataPropertyName value."

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to directly access the columns after you actually write the `.DataBind();`, like this, you can access and set any properties you want, like this:

`dataGridView_CRUD.Columns[0].Name = "Recipe";`

[DataGridView.Columns Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DataGridViewColumn Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can also use `GridView.RowDataBound` Event, to set properties of particular `rows` and `cells` in the rows.
This event is invoked upon each single row binding.
[GridView.RowDataBound Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)

The above is very powerful for your future changes as well, however If this does not suit your needs and you precisely just want to alter a column, then the

Comment: When i write dataGridView_CRUD.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode ="Fill"; The following error occur.... 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode'